# Javascript nested tree ranking

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, algorithm, tree

I've spent quite some time thinking about a certain problem, but I can't find a satisfactory solution and it's becoming a blocking issue for me.
The situation is as follows.

I'm writing a small Javascript library that manages a dynamic tree structure (no binary), and where the root / nodes are represented as objects in a json array:

```
var json = [{ text: "root", children: [
                {id: "id_1", text: "node_1", children:[
                    {id: "id_c1", text: "node_c1"}, 
                    {id: "id_c2", text: "node_c2", children: [
                        {id: "id_c2_c1", text: "node_c2_c1"}, 
                        {id: "id_c2_c2", text: "node_c2_c2"}, 
                        {id: "id_c2_c3", text: "node_c2_c3"}]},   
                    {id: "id_c3", text: "node_c3"}]}, 
                {id: "id_2", text: "node_2"}]}];
```

I have a few problems that are closely related (the first one being the core, the others resulting from it):

1. It seems not possible to rank nodes in a straight-forward way (top-to-bottom). Insertion / removal of nodes will screw up the ranking.
2. Secondary, because of this, I can't find a good way to implement the retrieval of an interval (array of nodes), when two nodes are given (start / end). This in the scope of a shift-select on a tree-menu:

[image]

3. Another consequence is that I can't maintain proper order of my nodes when making random selects and adding them to a temporary array (using command key - purpose to drag/drop in the same order as retrieved). Since I can't assign ranking to the nodes, I can't maintain their order.

The most obvious solution is to flatten the json array and re-index all the nodes on every manipulation (which obviously works), but I'm fairly certain that this is overall a rather bad idea (inefficient).

Another idea I came up with would be to attribute a certain "weight" to each node based on an algorithm (using index, level, etc). I can't however find a right way to calculate the weight. Moreover, it doesn't solve the problem, as inserting / removing random nodes seems to still require the index to be rebuilt.

Here is my current code: https://gist.github.com/kimgysen/9d066bdf095b853c4d0e67517a76777d

Any help or input on the matter would be greatly appreciated...

Note: I don't expect anyone to go through the entire code, it's more of a conceptual programming problem I'm stuck with. I'm satisfied with a conceptual solution, if any.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean exactly, but you don't need to maintain an index, you can count every time you want to retrieve by index. Look at "depth-first pre-order traversal". Obviously indices will change with insertion; if you don't want that, you can't use indices; you could use unique IDs instead.

Comment: @Amadan With index I meant to list the nodes at specific order and give a value according to their position from the top in order to be able to maintain any node's order against another across the entire tree. Not sure if I'm clear. I'll check your suggestion, thanks. Somehow I was looking for a way to re-index, but in a more optimized way than to re-index the entire tree. Considering a very large tree, I'm not sure about what this will do towards performance.

Comment: I see. For a very large tree, I agree, reindexing at change makes more sense. Still, pre-order traversal is the way to visit all nodes in the order you wanted.

Comment: @Amadan Thanks for the resource, I'm reading it now and it looks very interesting. Hope to find the answer to my questions here!

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
       [ {id: "root",      p_id: 0,        l_id: 0,          text: "website"},
         {id: "header",    p_id: "root",   l_id: 0,          text: "Parent: root, left: none"},
         {id: "nav",       p_id: "header", l_id: 0,          text: "Parent: header, left:none"},
         {id: "headline",  p_id: "header", l_id: "nav",      text: "Parent: header, left: nav"},
         {id: "promotion", p_id: "header", l_id: "headline", text: "Parent: header, left: headline"},
       ];
```

**Insert a node**

If a new node named 'new_node' need to be inserted before 'headline'.

```
{id: "new_node",      p_id: ,        l_id: ,          text: "Parent:header, left:nav"},
```

1. Find the element that id is 'headline'.
2. Copy its p_id and l_id to the new_node.
3. Update the l_id of the 'headline' to 'new_node'.

   ```
   {id: "headline",  p_id: "header", l_id: "new_node",      text: "Parent: header, left: new_node"}
   {id: "new_node",  p_id: "header", l_id: "nav",      text: "Parent: header, left: nav"},
   ```

**Delete a node**

Delete 'headline'.

1. Save the l_id of the headline, and delete the element.
2. Find all the elements that p_id is 'headline', delete them.
3. Find the element that 'l_id' is 'headline', change its l_id to the headline's.

This solution is derived from the "**hierarchical categories model**", every element may have children, and children may have children again. Besides that, every element within the 'parent node' need to know his direct sibling. I think this is a "Linked list" structure.

Here is a slide for [hierarchical categories model](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data)